# I'm making a good chord progression, but I'm stuck

Tags: theory, chord-progressions

It goes Dm, then C#Aug, and then something with the note B as the root. Can someone help me understand where this is going? I don't have a lot of music theory experience, so I'm sorry that I'm asking such a basic question.

Comment: A question to ask oneself: **why is the bass going to B?** There's nothing wrong with that at all, but it is an arbitrary decision. And if there's an answer to that question, perhaps use the principles of that logic to inform a decision on what chord to follow it with.

Comment: Very much a question with only opinions for answers - there's no other way! It will also depend a lot on what *voicings* are used. That C#+ is also A+, so could take the tune somewhere completely different. Or even back to Dm! Instead of asking for others' opinions, keep at it, and come up with at least half a dozen ideas of your own.Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

Your Dm and C#aug share two pitches. Dm = `D F A` and C#Aug = `C# F A`.<sup>1</sup> So, for those two chords, you're really just changing the lowest note. Since you hear B next, that would be a logical continuation: `D C# B`. Try keeping the top two notes the same again: `B F A`. Since we just heard a `D` in the Dm chord, our ears can hold onto the memory of that, so `B F A` will sound very much like `B D F A`, which is Bm7b5.

So try: `Dm C#Aug Bm7b5`. That is to say: `D F A`, `C# F A`, `B F A`.

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>The correct spelling of C#aug is `C# E# G##`; however, I've used the enharmonically equivalent `C# F A` to make clear the relationship to the Dmin chord. Augmented chords have three enharmonically equivalent instances, differentiated by spelling. In this case: C#aug = `C# E# G##`; Faug = `F A C#`; Aaug = `A C# E#`.</sub>

Comment: With my 'picky' hat on, C#+ is C#, E#, Gx. Worth mentioning for accuracy.

Comment: @Tim https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hNuhF84wwt0

Comment: Doesn't A+ have A C# and E#? Don't understand the last comment, or much else today, it seems...

Comment: @Tim It's a line from the move The Princess Bride — worth a watch if you've never seen. Around these parts it's up there with Monty Python and The Holy Grail for quotability.

Answer (score 3):

I was initially thinking along the lines of @Aaron and I think that is a nice solution (+1). However I also thought if you want a little contrast to the harmony at that point you could go to a G/B (a G triad with B in the bass). This gives you some nice chromatic and stepwise motion in the harmony:

C# to D or B

F to G

A to G or B.

That can possibly be followed by a Gm/Bb, continuing the descending bass motion.

Comment: I felt the bass run going down to C before it got to B, although that does sound like quite a few other songs.

Comment: @Tim I also thought of chromatic descending when I first read the question. You’re right, that has already been used in many other songs.

Answer (score 0):

From a purely creative standpoint, I followed your first two chords with Bmaj7, and then E6(11).

(This is on a guitar, mind you.)

That's where the muse took me.